# Trying to unwrap two numerical columns into multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

maybe anyone can help me out once again. I have 2 columns with numbers. I need an excel formula (filter??) that for all Ref values only the corresponding output values are placed in separate columns. The data in the columns could be up to 200 datapoints and the number of unique  references in the Ref column could be anything.
My test example

```
Output.    Ref
23.           45
26.           45
22.           45
24.            45
19.            35
18.            35
20.            35
18.            35
20.            40
21.            40
20.            40
19.            40
```

Results in:

```
Ref_45.      Ref_35.    Ref_40.      Etc.   Etc.   Etc. 
23.              19.            20
26.              18.            21
22.               20.           20
24.               18.           19
```

I tried something , but can’t get the output exactly in this way.
Hope you can help.
Greetings,
Ger
[1st attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnhN4.png)
[2nd better attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Yd9.png)
Hoever in the 2nd attempt i have empty cells before and after

Comment: "I tried something". What did you try, and why didn't it work? Can you replace the line of numbers with how the data looks in Excel?

Comment: Hi Spikey, I tried with first use UNIQUE to filter Ref and then used that with statement

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track with your 2nd attempt.

1. Add a count column to your data in column A. Put 1 in the first cell eg. A2. Then A3 becomes =IF(C3=C2,A2+1,1)
2. Use UNIQUE to filter ref and turn into columns.
3. Use MATCH to find the array position (AP) for the first occurrence of said ref column
4. Now put another count column before your ref columns -> this will be the lookup value.
5. Do a VLOOKUP on count column 1,2,3,4... on an array defined by OFFSET($A$1, match AP from #3, 0, length of output (4 in your example)**, 3), returning column 2 (output).

Now you will no longer have the empty cells!

- If you don't have a fixed length array of output for each ref column, adjust the variable height argument of offset according to the MATCH AP of the next adjacent ref column, i.e. AP_ref35 - AP_ref45

CHALLENGE: Replace the UNIQUE function step with a pivot table, especially if you don't have Office 2019 or 365

Comment: Dear Mobus, thanks, i think i understand more or less, sounds a bit too complicated for me, but if you can take my little dataset as shown and would you then be able to make the excel sheet inclusive of your formulas so i can trace and understand what you have done? I am not a super expert with Excel ....Thx Ger

Comment: From what you were doing with your 2nd attempt I thought you were at least a super expert :) I'll see what I can do a bit later. Concept wise, let me try and explain better: you want a repeating index 1, 2, 3, 4 to the left of output. In your other table, VLOOKUP will for each ref column, lookup the output value at index 1, then index 2 in the next row and so forth. The trick is to use offset to make the lookup table shift for each ref column so that vlookup only looks at that ref's four rows. Play with the offset function first so you understand how to select a range with it.

Comment: By the way, does every ref always have the exact same number of output values (e.g. 4 in your example)? If so you could have a running index 1,2,3... 11, 12 to the left of output. Then break up into a rectangular table with a simple formula in A1 =VLOOKUP(ROW()+(COLUMN()-1)*4, ref to all data, 2, FALSE)

Comment: Hi Mobus, no that can be any number , i use UNIQUE to determine the number of Unique values and based upon that i get a series of columns with the values.

Comment: @waardg hope this helps https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GwadwIblzi7aCaKHKGcz_d7H5tua282P/view?usp=sharing
Do tag the question as answered if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for an excellent example of your data and expected output.

With Excel O365

For the column Headers:

```
E1: =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(Ref))
```

For the data

```
E2: =FILTER(Output,Ref=E$1)
```

*and fill right as far as needed*

*(Replace `Ref` and `Output` with the range references)*

[image]

*With O365, there is also a `SORT` function in case you want to sort the column headers (or the data, or both)*